# Создание файла конфига

Tags: c#

Скажите, как в C#.NET создать файл конфига, пример его ниже:

- `##programmname = Тестовая прога`
- `##imagepath = D:\test.jpg`

Comment: Очень интересно зачем вам такой формат конфига? Чем не подходит стандартный xml?

Comment: Ну не знаю... просто видел подобное, вот и подумал научится делать подобное... а о xml не слыхал.. Да и мне нужно чтобы пользователь мог в любое время открыть файл блокнотом и внести изменения.

Comment: Если вы как о языке не слышале о xml то советую услышать...Мало ли пригодится... :D

Comment: Можно использовать стандартный ini -формат. По синтаксису почти как ваш пример, а поддержка в  .Net - нативная (afaik).

Comment: **Violet** очень интересно... можно по подробнее...?

**Fatahan** Попробую почитать литературу.Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте стандартные средства - зачем вам "велик"? Для веб проекта - это файл Web.config, для "десктопа" или консоли - App.config. Добавляется в проект: Add New Item -> Application configuration file. В каждом из данных конфиг файлов уже определены секции пользовательских настроек в виде: 
[image]

После этого доступ к данным "сеттингам" следующий:

```
string name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["programmname"];
```

Если вы все таки хотите реализовать описанный конфиг (причем без явной нужды в нем смысла нет), то либо парсинг файлов, либо кастомная сериализация.

Comment: А вопрос, а какой надо использовать

    using

? Просто при вводе я не вижу в списке эту команду

    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

Comment: using System.Configuration

Comment: Просто юсинга будет не достаточно - нужно еще добавить в проект ссылку на System.Configuration